# Hide TabBar and display UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, uitoolbar

At the startup of my iPhone application if the user isn't logged in I want to hide the tabbar and display a toolbar at the bottom with only two centered buttons (signup and login).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide the tabBar with

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Then you can hide/unhide the toolbar

```
toolBar.hidden = NO;
```

Toggle these again once the login is successful.

Comment: Is this a recent option? Because on the web I've found several posts with two self-made functions for hide/display tabbar.

Comment: Nope. I've been using this for over a year, and it wasn't new when I found it.